# IdentityServer4 override BadRequest for invalid_client

Tags: identityserver4

We have a basic IdentityServer implementation using ClientCredentials.  When a token is requested with an invalid secret, we're receiving an invalid_client error with a 400 BadRequest status.  What is the best way to override this response and return a 401 unauthorized?  We have a remote device accessing our api which expects a 401 for authentication errors.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to work with another project that works as a facade in the middle, connects to the `/connect/token` methods and then gives a different response having `401`. Here are some links: 
https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html 
[How to setup a Web API Facade pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767007/how-to-setup-a-web-api-facade-pattern)